# Distributing a list of values into a matrix without a value being repeated within a Row or within a Column using R

Tags: r

I have a list of compound ids and masses and I want to distribute the compounds and masses into individual dataframes without more than one compound with the same mass appearing within a column or a row as shown in the image below.

```
dfx <- data.frame(id = c("A_0401923-001-AA", "A_0401924-001-AA", "A_0401925-001-CF", "A_0402137-001-AA", "A_0402138-001-AA", "A_0402139-001-AA", "A_0402140-001-AA", "A_0402141-001-AA", "A_0402142-001-CF", "A_0402158-001-CN", "A_0402159-001-CN", "A_0403516-001-AA", "A_0403517-001-AA", "A_0403518-001-CF", "A_0403522-001-AA", "A_0403523-001-AA", "A_0403784-001-AA", "A_0403785-001-CF", "A_0403786-001-CF", "A_0403787-001-CF", "A_0403788-001-AA", "A_0403789-001-AA"),
                  mass = c("697.3475489", "697.3475489", "782.3461691", "634.259184", "618.3417352", "618.3417352", "636.2981563", "636.2981563", "782.3461691", "618.3417352", "634.259184", "634.259184", "729.31962", "728.3243711", "728.3243711", "729.31962", "771.4119607", "771.4119607", "783.3665702", "783.3665702", "784.3708241", "784.3708241"))
```

[image]

Comment: How do you decide which values should be blank ? Do you want the final output to be list of dataframes ?

Comment: I just randomly placed the blank columns. I had 22 compounds and 25 slots. The output need not be in the form of dataframe.

Comment: How many compounds do you have, @RanonKahn ?

Comment: The Compounds number could vary and the matrix size also could vary up to 8 x 12 (96 well plate). Based on number of compounds the plate numbers also would vary.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, this may help you.

```
nr <- 5
nc <- 5
n <- seq_len(nr*nc)

lapply(dfx, function(x) data.frame(matrix(x[n], nr, nc)))

#$id
#                X1               X2               X3               X4               X5
#1 A_0401923-001-AA A_0402139-001-AA A_0402159-001-CN A_0403523-001-AA A_0403788-001-AA
#2 A_0401924-001-AA A_0402140-001-AA A_0403516-001-AA A_0403784-001-AA A_0403789-001-AA
#3 A_0401925-001-CF A_0402141-001-AA A_0403517-001-AA A_0403785-001-CF             <NA>
#4 A_0402137-001-AA A_0402142-001-CF A_0403518-001-CF A_0403786-001-CF             <NA>
#5 A_0402138-001-AA A_0402158-001-CN A_0403522-001-AA A_0403787-001-CF             <NA>

#$mass
#           X1          X2          X3          X4          X5
#1 697.3475489 618.3417352  634.259184   729.31962 784.3708241
#2 697.3475489 636.2981563  634.259184 771.4119607 784.3708241
#3 782.3461691 636.2981563   729.31962 771.4119607        <NA>
#4  634.259184 782.3461691 728.3243711 783.3665702        <NA>
#5 618.3417352 618.3417352 728.3243711 783.3665702        <NA>
```

Comment: This answer is satisfying the uniqueness of the Row content. However, the Columns have the same mass number repeated in all columns (the content of rows 1 and 2  are the same). Is it possible to make the column unique by rearranging compounds (masses) programmatically?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood you correctly but you can use `lapply(dfx, function(x) data.frame(matrix(sample(x[n]), nr, nc)))` to shuffle the values randomly in the matrix.

Comment: You are almost correct and I very much appreciate your effort in finding a solution and valuable suggestions. However, even after over 1000 iterations incorporating sample() function as suggested, the result is not satisfying the row and column value uniqueness. Besides that, the Compound and Compound Mass pairing does not match.